# Как результат цикла поместить в чанк через функцию?

Tags: modx

Хочу результат цикла поместить в чанк через функцию. Что я делаю не так?

```
class MyClass
{
function chunk($data) {
global $modx;
return $out .= $modx->getChunk($tpl,['name'=> $data]);
    }
}
$myclass = new MyClass;

foreach ($array as $value){
 $data = $value[data];

 $myclass->chunk($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

переменную $tpl по такому принципу в вашем случае надо формировать

```
$tpl = $modx->getOption('tpl', $scriptProperties, '@INLINE <div>[[+name]]</div>');
```